# Swift SpriteKit SKSpriteNode's "Sometimes" Don't Show Up

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2, skspritenode

I am making an iOS using Swift and SpriteKit. However I am experiencing irregularity in the running of my app. Sometimes the ship SKSpriteNodes doesn't appear on the screen, sometimes the bullet's SKSpriteNodes don't appear, sometimes everything shows up fine (I add the bullets elsewhere in the code). In all cases I am not making changes to the code between runs. I am starting the app on this screen directly so I'm thinking maybe it has something to do with these SKSpriteNodes not having enough time to initialize. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18):

Set the `zPosition` of the `self.ship` so that it is in front of the background nodes.  Something like this (I would do this after setting the position):

```
self.ship.zPosition = 1.0
```

You can also use negatives in the `zPosition`, for instance, to drop the `self.background` down.  Think of `zPosition` as layers (with support for decimals), the higher the number, the closer to the "top" of the layer stack your node will be.

Comment: He could also set the opacity of all his sprites to 0.5 temporarily,  to see if any of them is hiding behind another. If they still don't show up, he can then be sure it is not about depth and that there's something else wrong.

Comment: Thank you a thousand times. That was the issue!

Comment: @mpkostek Awesome, glad to help.